# Google Pie chart: remove white gap between pie slices

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, pie-chart

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784246/removing-the-white-line-between-slices-in-flot-pie-chart/22227464), but for Google Pie Charts:

How can I remove the white lines between the slices on a Google Pie Chart:

[image]

On the image above, I want to remove the white space highlighted by the green arrow.

Comment: Just FYI, it would be better to include the code you're working with in the question body rather than relying on links to outside sources.  I know Google seems like a safe bet to always be there, but they have been shutting down a lot of free services lately.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get rid of that gap by setting the `pieSliceBorderColor` to `"transparent"`.  Try the following on [Google Code Playground](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#pie_chart):

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work', 11],
    ['Eat', 2],
    ['Commute', 2],
    ['Watch TV', 2],
    ['Sleep', 7]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
    draw(data, {title:"So, how was your day?", pieSliceBorderColor:"transparent"});
}
```