# Removing the white line between slices in Flot pie chart

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, charts, flot, pie-chart

How can I remove the `white line` between `slices` and `background` in `Flot` `pie chart`?

[My jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/canttouchit/6hHDt/1/)

As you can see it looks like that:

[image: White line]

I want it to  look like that(Ignore my bad artistic skills):

[image]

**My Code:**

```
$(function () {
     var data = [
    { label: "Read", data: 50, color: '#614E43' },
    { label: "Unread", data: 150, color: '#F5912D' }];
      $.plot($("#star"), data, 
      {
        series: {

          pie: { 

              radius: 0.2,  
            innerRadius: 0.125,
            show: true
          }
        }
      });
});
```

Comment: If you have the same need but for Google Pie Charts API, see this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22228074/google-pie-chart-how-can-i-remove-the-white-line-between-slices/22228088#22228088

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add the STROKE Property

```
pie: {               
  radius: 0.2,  
  innerRadius: 0.125,
  show: true,
  stroke: { 
      width: 0.1
  }
}
```

Set the value to 0 totally hide the pie.

So you could also add a stroke color, with the value set to the same color as your background :

```
pie: {
    radius: 0.2,
    innerRadius: 0.125,
    show: true,
    stroke: {
        width: 0.1,
        color: '#808080'
    }
}
```

See the Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hSmVH/

Comment: or just add -- color: 'none'

Comment: setting width:0 does not work, it shows a border of 1px. Setting color:'none' causes hole of doughnut to disappear reverting back to a full pie again. Also width:0.1 still shows a border for doughnut charts larger than say 200px diameter, this gets worse as doughnut charts get bigger.

Comment: I take that back setting stroke width:0 does work, this has been fixed in a newer version of Flot than the one I was using