# Google Pie Chart: How can I remove the white line between slices?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, pie-chart

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784246/removing-the-white-line-between-slices-in-flot-pie-chart/22227464), but for Google Pie Charts:

How can I remove the white lines between the slices on a Google Pie Chart:

[image]

On the image above, I want to remove the white space highlighted by the green arrow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google pie charts: remove white gap between segments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410695/google-pie-charts-remove-white-gap-between-segments)

Comment: @AntoJurković yes! same question, same answer. I will edit the other question and its tags to allow it to show up more easily on the search query I used before asking.

Answer (score 6):

Use the configuration option `pieSliceBorderColor` with the value `transparent` ([see documentation here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#Configuration_Options)).

```
  new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
  draw(data, {
                pieSliceBorderColor : "transparent", // Add this line
                title : "So, how was your day?"
              }
      );
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Fiddle with it: http://jsfiddle.net/PWc43/